# JSF 2.1 CSRF safe?

Tags: java, jsf, csrf

Is the Mojarra 2.1.1 (SNAPSHOT 20110404) version and higher already protected against CSRF? Are the ajax requests also safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [spec sheet](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http://javaserverfaces.java.net/presentations/20090520-jsf2-datasheet.pdf&ei=ed7_TcvDDIfi0QHZ29G7Cg&usg=AFQjCNEzTtaeEAhpj_yi5K9-Mabm7gkqpA) says it is.  Why would AJAX be any different?

Comment: Thanks, i don't know why it should be different. I am just asking because many posts about this topic are not really clear.

Comment: @jeanne: i also found this document, but in most posts in Stack Overflow i read: JSF will be CSRF-safe in 2.2 - not before - it's in [JSR 869](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/edburns/archive/2011/11/11/jsf-22-early-draft-review-available) defined. So I don't know why Sun wrote this into their document.